# ElasticSearch not returning any results?

Tags: javascript, search, elasticsearch, angular

I am sure I've missed something, but I am trying to get started with ElasticSearch. I have a remote search server set up with [`www.searchly.com`](http://www.searchly.com) and am using [ElasticSearch-js](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js) to interact with it. I have set up an index with searchly, which you can see is populated (as shown in the screenshot below).

[image]

Now I am using this in an angular2 component, in the constructor I have:

```
constructor() {
  var connectionString = 'http://xyz@bifur-eu-west-1.searchly.com';
  this._client = new elasticsearch.Client({ host: connectionString, log: 'trace' });
}
```

and the in the ngOnInit lifecycle hook, I had:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._client.ping({
      // ping usually has a 3000ms timeout
      requestTimeout: Infinity,

      // undocumented params are appended to the query string
      hello: "elasticsearch!"
    }, function (error) {
      if (error) {
        console.trace('elasticsearch cluster is down!');
      } else {
        console.log('All is well');
      }
    });
}
```

which worked fine and showed the cluster is alive and my client is successfully connecting to it. However, I then changed the ping to:

```
this._client.search({
  index: 'plugins',
  type: '_all',
  body: {
    query: {
      match: {
        name: 'Contacts'
      }
    }
  }
}).then(function (resp) {
  var hits = resp.hits.hits;
}, function (err) {
  console.trace(err.message);
});
```

which as you can see from the screenshot, should return a value, but instead I get this in my browser's console:

```
TRACE: 2016-10-03T08:43:04Z
  -> POST http://bifur-eu-west-1.searchly.com/plugins/_all/_search
  {
    "query": {
      "match": {
        "name": "Contacts"
      }
    }
  }
  <- 200
  {
    "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
    },
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false
  }
```

Why isn't this query returning a result?

Comment: For some reason, the query in the browser console has the search name 'Bluetooth', when in the client search you have hardcoded 'Contacts'. Why would those be different? Do you have a 'Bluetooth' record in your index?

Comment: @WithoutRemorse Oh yes, sorry, there is a Bluetooth record and that is what I was originally searching for. I changed the query for the question to reflect the visible records in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Caught it! Turns out there is a backend bug with searchly, which requires you to use an explicit `type` in your query, or no type at all, so by changing to:

```
this._client.search({
  index: 'plugins',
  body: {
    query: {
      match: {
        name: 'Contacts'
      }
    }
  }
}).then(function (resp) {
  var hits = resp.hits.hits;
}, function (err) {
  console.trace(err.message);
});
```

I get the correct result!